# Bootstrap 3 navbar collapse menu forcing image down while navbar-fixed-top possible?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to figure out how to make the navbar collapse act a specific way and not sure if it's possible.

I'm just using the default navbar but added fixed-to-top class to the nav, the default action of this navbar(without navbar-fixed-top)is that collapsed menu when clicked will force whatever content is underneath is to move down when the menu opens. When I add the navbar-fixed-top class to the nav, it doesn't push the content below it down, instead, the menu that drops down covers the content underneath it.

Basically, I want the nav to be fixed to the top, but I want the collapsed menu to push the content beneath it.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="navbar-header">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be a more elegant way to do it, but here is a little JavaScript that will add `padding-top` to the `body` when the menu opens and remove it when closed, giving the illusion that the content is being pushed down by the `navbar-collapse`.

A bit hackish, but it works...

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FEGtq)

```
var navHeight = $('.navbar-collapse').height();

$('.navbar-collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function(){
  if($(this).height() != 0){
     navHeight = $(this).height();
  }
  $('body').animate({
    'padding-top': parseInt($("body").css("padding-top")) + navHeight
   }, 300);
});

$('.navbar-collapse').on('hide.bs.collapse', function(){
  navHeight = $(this).height();
  $('body').animate({
    'padding-top': parseInt($("body").css("padding-top")) - navHeight
   }, 300);
});
```